# Ruled emails in Outlook still trigger alert when replied to from an email chain

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules

At my company, I receive emails from multiple office locations. I have successfully filtered out emails from another states office via Rules in Outlook.

I accomplished this by using the states abbreviation which is in the body of the initial Email. The email is automatically marked and read, and sent to a separate folder.

However, when people reply to this email chain, it then shows up in my regular inbox.

Is there a way to keep all replies to a Ruled email in the folder it was originally sent to, and keep them muted?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no rules to move replies to messages from someone. Perhaps you can try to set rules based on other conditions, such as subject.